# Ember-CLI - Exclude modules originating from addons from JSHint

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, jshint

I am looking to exclude modules originating from addons from JSHint, when i run tests in my project. Because of this i am having too many failed test JSHint test cases.

Small excerpt from list of failed test cases.
As you can see my-addon-components is custom addon which is used in my project.

```
JSHint - modules/my-addon-components/components/web-grid.js: should pass jshint (1, 0, 1)Rerun2 ms
JSHint - modules/my-addon-components/components/web-map.js: should pass jshint (1, 0, 1)Rerun2 ms
JSHint - modules/my-addon-components/components/web-textarea.js: should pass jshint (1, 0, 1)Rerun2 ms
JSHint - modules/my-addon-components/helpers/format-number.js: should pass jshint (1, 0, 1)Rerun
```